# Nested directive not firing on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am having an issue with nested directives. I have two directives:

MainDir.js

```
(function(){angular.module("mod").directive("mainDir", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {   
    },
    templateUrl: "components/main.html"
};
});})();
```

Main.html

```
<div>Main html</div>
<childDir> </childDir>
```

childDir.js

```
(function(){angular.module("mod").directive("childDir", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {   
    },
    templateUrl: "components/child.html"
};
});})();
```

child.html

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

On page load, I get the text in the div in main.html but the directive doesnt load. I've set some breakpoints in the link function and it's not getting there.

Comment: in directive `childDir.js` change `templateUrl` to `template`. and you never call `<mainDir></mainDir>`

Comment: I put the html inline for question simplicity, I changed it to use a template. Maindir is called on the index and is loading fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

In `childDir.js`, change `templateUrl` to `template`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the tag for the child directive needed to be written as

```
<child-dir></child-dir>
```

It worked after this..